# PowerShell Recursive copying and pause between each file is copied

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have the following script to recursive copy data and create a log file of the destination, could any assist please, I would like to pause for 10 seconds after each file is copied so each file allocated a different created time stamp.

```
$Logfile ='File_detaisl.csv'
$SourcePath = Read-Host 'Enter the full path containing the files to copy'
""
""
$TargetPath = Read-Host 'Enter the destination full path to copy the files'
""
#$str1FileName = "File_Details.csv"

Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath -Destination $TargetPath -recurse -Force

Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetPath -Recurse -Force -File  | Select-Object Name,DirectoryName,Length,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,@{N='MD5 Hash';E={(Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 $_.FullName).Hash}},@{N='SHA-1 Hash';E={(Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 $_.FullName).Hash}} | Sort-Object -Property Name,DirectoryName | Export-Csv -Path $TargetPath$Logfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Copy-Item` has a `-PassThru` parameter that outputs each item that is currently processed. By piping to `ForEach-Object` you can add a delay after each file.

```sh
Copy-Item -Path $SourcePath -Destination $TargetPath -recurse -Force -PassThru | 
    Where-Object PSIsContainer -eq $false |
    ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep 10 }
```

The `Where-Object` is there to exclude folders from the `ForEach-Object` processing. For folder items the `PSIsContainer` property is `$true` and for files it is `$false`.

Comment: Thank you, the files contained within subfolders appear to have have matching creation timestamps, is there away for all files and folders to have different time stamps?

Comment: @PF6004 I cannot reproduce. Did you clear the output folder before? Btw, if you want this for folders too, remove the `Where-Object` line, so it waits after creation of folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would lose the integrity of the folder structure, but one way to do this is using `Get-ChildItem` then piping to `Foreach-Object`, or using a loop to iterate through the items one at time.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Recurse -Force | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $TargetPath -Force
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }
```

The purpose is to get the files processed one after another using a loop in order to place our `Start-Sleep` after the file has been copied.